# Align text on bottom

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with css/html that I am finding hard to solve. Lets say we have a link and a h2 inside it such that it looks like below

[image: Images with lines of one line and two lines]

The code is as below:

```
<a href="newLink"><h2>This can be one line or two lines or three..</h2></a>
```

I need the lines align bottom as below...Also please note that the text is centered too as well as on the bottom. How to do this?

```
                                    Andis AGC Clipper Single
Andis AGC 2 Speed Clipper                     Speed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
<div>
 <h2>one line</h2>
  <h2 align=center>This can be one line or two lines or three..</h2>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div{background:grey; width:100%}
h2{
  font-size:20px; 
  color:white; width:49%; 
  display:inline-block
}
```

Edited the Sowmya demo for center align.

Comment: I solved it using vertical-align: bottom; display:table-cell   I have not tested it yet using all browsers.

Answer (score 2):

**HTML**

```
<div>
 <h2>one line</h2>
   <h2>This can be one line or two lines or three..</h2>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div{background:grey; width:100%}
h2{
  font-size:20px; 
  color:white; width:49%; 
  background:red;
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:center
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ovupuw/5/edit)**